# household_database visualization

Tags: ros, rviz, household-objects-database, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am trying to visualize with rviz the objects triangle mesh stored in the database. I call the household database GetModelMesh service and I put the returned points in a Marker for rviz visualization. I have noticed that every time I call the service GetModelMesh the value for mesh type is 0 which should be sphere. If I send the mesh vertices extracted to rviz and I set the marker type as sphere I always get the same sphere shape. Maybe I am missing something. How can I save the triangle mesh in a marker? It is correct that I get always a 0 as type from the GetModelMesh even if I change the object Id?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9739/household_database-visualization/) by [cmsoda](https://answers.ros.org/users/430/cmsoda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-04-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just want to see them you can try spawning the objects in gazebo.
I have urdfs for them here:
http://people.csail.mit.edu/mitko/gazebo_stuff/household/urdf/
make sure to turn off shadows in gazebo though - you might get an error similar to this:
http://answers.ros.org/question/1550/shadows-of-the-household-objects-in-gazebo

Here are also some useful RVIZ markers (which you have probably seen already)
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Troubleshooting

---

Originally posted by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) with karma: 535 on 2011-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) on 2011-07-22**:
Also, the fact that the returned shape type is always 0 is a bug, which has been fixed for upcoming releases. The type should be 3, for MESH.